# asymptotics and calculating it

Tags: asymptotics

I have a task to show by definition that

$\ln n^{2} + 1 = \Theta (\ln n)$

by definition , we know that we have to find c1 and c2  such as

$c_{1} * \ln n<\ln n^{2} + 1 < c_{2} * (\ln n)$

we can find find c2 easily

$\ln n^{2} + 1 < c_{2} * (\ln n)$

$2*\ln n + 1 < c_{2} * (\ln n)$

so we know that c2 hast to be  c2 >= 3.

c1 is the same story

$c_{1} * \ln  n< 2*\ln n + 1 
$

we see that c1 <= 2

My question is from students point of view. Is it legit to assume that c2 >= 3 and 0 < c1 <= 2 because we "see it" or do we have to prove it by some further calculation?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I do not see anything wrong , what did u meant by it? I may be explaining it poorly , but  i cannot think of another way of explaining it.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam the second one

Comment: @AbdallahHammam now i see what you meant by it , it should be ln n , im going to edit question.

Answer (score 1):

As

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{ln(n^2)+1}{ln(n)}=$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(2+\frac{1}{ln(n)})=\color{green}{2}$$

with$\;\;\epsilon=1$ for example,

$$\exists N>0: \forall n\geq N$$

$$1<\frac{ln(n^2)+1}{ln(n)}<3$$

So, you can take  $c_1=1\;$ and$\;c_2=3$  .